# How to know whether chef-server is install on VM?

Tags: chef-infra

After the Chef server is installed, and I run the reconfigure command:

$ sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure

In the end, it state Chef Client finished, opscode Reconfigured!

So I was wondering did I install Chef Server to it or chef client?

Comment: Chef-server install use chef client in local mode to configure itself, create config files, etc. so you installed chef-server yes.

Answer (score 1):

You installed both.  The installer for chef-server is really just a set of cookbooks that run with chef-solo.  If the `chef-server-ctl` command exists, then you installed the server (which also installs the client).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for helping. So how do I remove to just want it to be Chef-server itself?

Comment: You don't.  You'll want to keep chief client around so you can still run check server-ctrl, which uses chef-client.